# QMenu only showing on QPushButton when calling QPushButton.menu()

Tags: python-3.x, qt, pyside2

With the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5234662/9417210) example, I don't get the menu on the button. It will just remain a simple button.

```
    menu = QMenu()
    Act1 = QtWidgets.QAction("Action 1", menu)
    Act1.setCheckable(True)
    Act2 = QtWidgets.QAction("Action 2", menu)
    Act2.setCheckable(True)
    menu.addAction(Act1)
    menu.addAction(Act2)

    btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Multiselection")
    btn.setMenu(menu)
```

But it somehow works when calling `btn.menu()` after the last line above. Unfortunately, this line will also cause python to stop working upon closing the app.

PyCharm output:
`Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)`

If it helps: I'm using PySide2 version 2.0.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`QPushButton.setMenu` [does not take ownership of the menu](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpushbutton.html#setMenu). You need to parent the menu: `menu = QMenu(yourParentQObjectDescendent)`. In your code, the menu will be destroyed after the enclosing method returns.

0xC0000005 is an Access Violation. Wrongly unparented QObjects and descendents are a frequent cause of it in PyQt.